# In the context, the translation of the phrase FLASHY BOI "5 hours of debugging VS / flashy boi"

Tags: meaning, phrases, slang, translation, jokes

In the context, the translation of the phrase  FLASHY BOI?

"5 hours of debugging VS / flashy boi"

Comment: It would help if you provided the actual context...?  It sounds like the text from one of those "difficult choice" memes.

Comment: In **what** context? Googling the phrase turns up no results at all apart from this question. Did you make this up yourself?

Comment: Sounds like "flashy boi" is someone's handle?

Answer (score 1):

The context is likely a meme asking "who would win, the thing on the left or the thing on the right?"

> **Who Would Win?** is an image macro series posing the question "who would win" in various hypothetical battles between two opposing subjects.
>
> https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/who-would-win

The original template pitted two reasonably matched opponents against each other.  The trend now is to put a reasonable idea or a realistic thing on the left, and a silly idea or character on the right. For whatever reason, the language used to describe the silly character on the right often includes the word "boi":

> Who would win?
>
> Highly skilled and talented people who put time and effort into producing content | One yellow boi
>
> https://knowyourmeme.com/photos/1301184-who-would-win

This use of "boi" is not restricted to this meme format. It's reasonably widely used on reddit and in related contexts. It seems to mean *guy*, as in, *a person, a fellow, an individual*. However, it's often used to refer to non-human or even non-living things.  "[What's the whole "[adjective] boi" thing about?](https://www.reddit.com/r/OutOfTheLoop/comments/78xfu2/whats_the_whole_adjective_boi_thing_about/)"

This use of *boi* in place of *guy* appears to me as another example of the baby-talk slang that's often used in these internet-meme sharing groups.

Answer (score 0):

Can have a lot of meanings. Colloquially it can be used to refer to a boy. In the LGBT community it can refer to range of identities, generally associated with “butch” lesbians. Flashy can mean stylish, or perhaps trendy (I feel that the word obnoxious might also need to go in there somewhere). So a well dressed childish person, or butch lesbian or trans. There is not enough context to determine what the appropriate context is. It could be a discussion, debugging could also refer to trying to reprogram an LGBT person if the speaker believes they are brainwashed (which falls into some beliefs about the LbGT community). Flashy Boi could also be a name someone uses online, not unlike LoganRoku.